# Vectorization in CUDA Fortran

Tags: cuda, fortran, gpu, vectorization

. How could I use instruction like LDS.128 in CUDA Fortran to do vectorization?

Are there some methods in CUDA Fortran to do vectorization like CUDA C/C++:

```c
// data is a floating points array
float4 *data_vec = (float4 *)data;

// Using vectorized loading instruction
float4 d1 = data_vec[0];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cuda fortran doesn't have explicit support for the standard vector types exposed in the C++ CUDA dialect. If there are opportunities for using vectorised memory transaction in your code, you will have to rely on the compilers to identify and emit them.

Comment: Or maybe use OpenMP simd directives to help the compiler

Comment: Thanks for your answer. You are right. I found a blog and achieved the vectorized loading using a "special" method (my hardware: NVIDIA Tesla V100-SXM2-16GB (Volta) and compiler: NVIDIA HPC SDK 22.2). Blog link: https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/how-to-do-efficient-vectorized-loads-in-cuda-fortran/186344